# color selector for activatedBackgroundIndicator not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have a selected item from a list view stay highlighted.  after searching, activatedBackgroundIndicator should be the easy way to go, but I can't seem to get it working.  Here is my code segment

for my individual item layout, I have res/layout/simplerow.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >
</TextView>
```

and my color selector, I have res/drawable/playerbg.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_selected"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_activated"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_pressed" />
</selector>
```

I can see that the color selector is working because when I press on one of the item, I get the picture_frame_pressed.  but I can't get any of the color to stay high lighted.  I am using API 17 running on a real device with android 4.2